# DensityPlot with contours in LogScale

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I have always had this problem to use DensityPlot in Logscale along with ContourPlot. Here is my code

```
q = 1.6*10^-19;
hbar := 6.63/(2*\[Pi])*10^-34;
m0 = 9.1*10^-31;
kb = 1.38*10^-23;
eps0 = 8.85*10^-12;
meff = 0.22*m0;
ClearAll["Global`*"] (*Clear all variables*)
q = 1.6*10^-19;
hbar := 6.63/(2*\[Pi])*10^-34;
m0 = 9.1*10^-31;
kb = 1.38*10^-23;
eps0 = 8.85*10^-12;
meff = 0.22*m0;
Piezo[x_] := 0.026 (1 - x) + 0.0248 x (1 - x);
PspAlGaN[x_] := 0.090 x + 0.034 (1 - x) - 0.021 x (1 - x);
Pnet[x_] := Piezo[x] + PspAlGaN[1] - PspAlGaN[x];
nsAlGaN[x_, \[Phi]b_] := ( 
  q*(2*(0.2 + 0.2 x) m0)/(2 \[Pi] hbar^2)*(9.14*eps0)/(15*10^-9))/( 
  q^2*(2*(0.2 + 0.2 x) m0)/(2 \[Pi] hbar^2) + 
   2 (9.14*eps0)/(15*10^-9) + 
   2 ((8.9 + 0.24 x)*eps0)/(15*10^-9))*(-\[Phi]b + 
    Pnet[x]/(9.14*eps0)*15*10^-9 - 15/24* (2.8*x + 3.4))*10^-4
a = DensityPlot[nsAlGaN[x, \[Phi]b], {x, 0, 1}, {\[Phi]b, 0.5, 3}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 15}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "SBH (eV)"}, FrameStyle -> Black, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Linear", "Log"}]
b = ContourPlot[nsAlGaN[x, \[Phi]b], {x, 0, 1}, {\[Phi]b, 0.5, 3}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 15}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "SBH (eV)"}, FrameStyle -> Black, 
  ContourShading -> None, ContourLabels -> All, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Linear", "Log"}]
Show[a, b]
```

[image]

You get this figure. Now the ContourPlot values are in Log but I actually want them to represent numbers such as 1x10^{13}, 2x10^{13} instead of 30, 30.5 which are basically Log of those values. So essentially, I want the plot to remain in Log Scale but the numbers to be shown in Linear scale.

Comment: Does it work if you give `ContourPlot` the option `ContourLabels -> (Inset[nsAlGaN[#1, #2], {#1, #2}] &)`?

Comment: It worked, Thanks! But how do I choose some particular contour values such as 1e13, 2e13 etc. Also, what is your code doing exactly?